# What is a modern way to persist an XML object into a database?

Tags: java, xml, database, hibernate, mapping

My workplace gave me the task to map out the frameworks and libraries that we will use in an upcoming project. I'm not well versed in some of the areas and one of them is the following:

We are calling a 3rd party API that returns an XML that is several thousand lines long, each XML contains the data related to a single person.

We need to map each person's data to our database. Our previous architect suggested we use Hibernate to parse the XMLs into data transfer objects.

Is hibernate the way to go or is there a simpler/more efficient or more modern way of achieving this?

The system calling the 3rd party API is built with Java, JAX-RS. We have oracle databases.

Comment: Recommending software, frameworks etc is considered off-topic for stackoverflow

Comment: The reason StackOverflow discourages such questions is that no professional consultant would dream of making a recommendation on application architecture without digging much more deeply into your requirements; in consequence, the only answers you get will be anecdotal, unreliable, and based on limited personal experience.

Comment: Anyway, what's so great about being "modern"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd agree, this is really off-topic for the site, however, I'd suggest using FasterXML/Jackson. The library allows you to convert the XML into java objects. Once they are in object form, you can go ahead and do something with hibernate.

Take a look here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: Hmm, if you think it is off-topic then why do you answer?

Comment: I learned something new about stackoverflow. I'll mark Dans answer as correct as it answers my question and I will respect the guideline in the future. Thank you.